# Standard list of values for a contact's name prefix dropdown box?

Tags: forms, validation, user-input

Is there a list of what values would be expected to be available in a list of name prefixes when filling out a contact form on a website?

For example:  Dr., Mr., Ms., etc.

Also, is giving a choice of name prefixes preferable to free text input?

Comment: Why do sites bother with this?

Comment: @Barmar, possibly, when your primary audience has a prefix such as Dr, they might like to distinguish themselves as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_honorifics

Actually i would say do not use prefixes at all, most part Europe does not.

Comment: Or even better: http://notes.ericwillis.com/2009/11/common-name-prefixes-titles-and-honorifics/

Answer (score 6):

I know this is pretty old by this point and probably not searched very much, but I created a gist for copy pasting the common ones.

Here is the code, or you can use the github gist link below.

```
<select name="prefix" id="prefix">
    <option value="Ms"> Ms </option> 
    <option value="Miss"> Miss </option> 
    <option value="Mrs"> Mrs </option> 
    <option value="Mr"> Mr </option> 
    <option value="Master"> Master </option> 
    <option value="Fr"> Father (Fr) </option>
    <option value="Rev"> Reverend (Rev) </option>
    <option value="Dr"> Doctor (Dr) </option> 
    <option value="Atty"> Attorney (Atty) </option>  
    <option value="Hon"> Honorable (Hon) </option>  
    <option value="Prof"> Professor (Prof) </option>  
    <option value="Pres"> President (Pres) </option> 
    <option value="VP"> Vice President (VP) </option> 
    <option value="Gov"> Governor (Gov) </option>  
    <option value="Ofc"> Officer (Ofc) </option> 
</select>
```

https://gist.github.com/ddavisgraphics/6f8e28310a622b058833900e46e49e0a

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a common reason for [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12382359)

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ I changed my answer to reflect the contents of the link.  Hope that helps, my apologies.

Comment: @DavidJ.Davis That helps a lot. Thanks